# javascript automatic timeout button action

Tags: javascript, html, button, settimeout

```
window.setTimeout(function() {window.location = document.getElementById('redirect')[0].onclick;}, 2000);
```

Hi guys, what's wrong in this, please? 
All it should do is:
 activate an element with id="redirect" which's onclick is :to go back in history.

```
<a id="redirect" onclick="window.history.back()">Go back (auto after 2sec)</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the element click after 2 seconds you can do this:

```
window.setTimeout( function() {
    document.getElementById('redirect').click();
}, 2000);

<a id="redirect" onclick="window.history.back()">Go back (auto after 2sec)</a>
```

or you could do:

```
 window.setTimeout( function() {
    window.history.back()
}, 2000);

<a id="redirect" onclick="window.history.back()">Go back (auto after 2sec)</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works properly only in Google Chrome, though. In firefox & IE it doesnt work. The countdown of 2 sec doesnt work and the page doesnt redirect itself.

Answer (score 3):

Window.Location cannot receive a "window.history.back()" value. 
You must do that:

```
<a id="redirect" onclick="javascript:window.setTimeout(function() window.history.back(), 2000);">Go back (auto after 2sec)</a>
```